# Displaying image in Listview through JSON

Tags: android

Iam using JSON to import data from database. Iam getting the data also from the database. Iam getting the data in an array. Here I am getting a data in variable img as a url and now I want to show this path url in the Listview. How to do it possible. Please tell me ??

```
            package com.abc;

            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.HashMap;
            import java.util.List;

            import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
            import org.json.JSONArray;
            import org.json.JSONException;
            import org.json.JSONObject;

            import android.app.ListActivity;
            import android.app.ProgressDialog;
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.os.AsyncTask;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.AdapterView;
            import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
            import android.widget.ListAdapter;
            import android.widget.ListView;
            import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
            import android.widget.TextView;
            import android.widget.Toast;

            public class FoodView extends ListActivity 
            {
                private ProgressDialog pDialog;

                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

                private static String url_all_products = "http://ambrogroup.com/app/index/file/food";
                private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
                private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
                private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
                private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
                private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "img";
                private static final String TAG_DESTINATION = "destination";
                private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";

                JSONArray products = null;

            @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
                {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.food_view);

                    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();        // Hashmap for ListView
                    new LoadAllProducts().execute();                                // Loading products in Background Thread by explicit function


                    ListView listview = getListView();                                  // Get listview

                    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {         // on seleting single product // launching Edit Product Screen
            @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
                        {
                            //getting values from selected ListItem
                            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText().toString();
                            String pname = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                            String pimg = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.img)).getText().toString();
                            String pdestination = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.destination)).getText().toString();
                            String pprice = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price)).getText().toString();
                        }
                    });

                }

            class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
            {       
                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() 
                    {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FoodView.this);
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading list. Please wait...");
                        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                        pDialog.show();
                    }

                    /**
                     * getting All products from url
                     * */
                    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        // getting JSON string from URL
                        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

                        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                        Log.d("Getting all the list : ", json.toString());

                        try {
                            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                            if (success == 1) 
                            {
                                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
                                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) 
                                {
                                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                                    String img = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                                    String destination = c.getString(TAG_DESTINATION);
                                    String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);

                                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                                    map.put(TAG_IMAGE, img);
                                    map.put(TAG_DESTINATION, destination);
                                    map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);

                                    productsList.add(map);
                                }
                            } 
                            else 
                            {

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return null;
                    }

                    /**
                     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                     * **/
                    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        // updating UI from Background Thread
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                /**
                                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                                 * */
                                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                        FoodView.this, productsList,R.layout.list_view, new String[] {TAG_PID,TAG_NAME,TAG_IMAGE,TAG_DESTINATION,TAG_PRICE},new int[] 
                                        { 
                                        R.id.pid, R.id.name,R.id.img,R.id.destination, R.id.price 
                                        });
                                // updating listview
                                setListAdapter(adapter);
                            }
                        });

                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: explore this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Answer (score 1):

Use this library
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

It provides you easy way to show images by url in any place, includes ListView. Just use:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

Comment: please give me the simplest way of code. error is showing unable to decode the stream while iam executing with an external image link

Comment: I updated my answer, it should works. Before this code you should also to setap library properly. Follow this guide: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#quick-setup If you still have problems, please submit your code and url of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Concentrate on Many Concepts like Memory Leak, Loading Efficiently, Bitmap Resize with scaling and JSON data Retrieval. Kindly go-through this link then you will get an idea.

http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134